# Illegal characters in path from class

Tags: c#

I'm stuck in a stupid error but I can't figure it out, could you please help me out?

What
I'm trying to create a class that will have several methods which will perform many different regex in a given text file. This text file is passed in from the main program to the class. 
The class then consumes the text file and perform each regex where I call from the main program by instantiating each object in the class.

Problem
When I pass the file, I created a function within the class to count the lines of the file and loop through each line counting how many times such regex match happens.

```
  //CountLines Function
    static long CountLinesInFile(string f)
    {
        long count = 0;
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                count++;
            }
            return count;

        }
    }
```

This CountLines function will provide the lines to be looped through by the object as in:

```
private string configfile;    
    public string ConfigFile
    {
        get { return this.configfile; }
        set { this.configfile = value; }
    }

    public void objects()
    {
        //Counting Object Group Network
        int objCount = Lines(configfile)
            .Select(line => Regex.Matches(line, @"object-group network").Count)
            .Sum();

        //Ending of Counting Object Group Network
    }
```

from the main program Im trying to call the class and get the results by doing this:

```
Cisco newCisco = new Cisco();
        newCisco.ConfigFile = richTextBox1.Text;
        newCisco.objects();
```

I'm getting stuck at the class at the `using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))` line with an Illegal characters in path:

> Exception:Thrown: "Illegal characters in path." (System.ArgumentException)
>   A System.ArgumentException was thrown: "Illegal characters in path."
>   Time: 8/13/2014 1:58:01 AM
>   Thread:Main Thread[1304]

I know that I'm making a mistake but I can find where, and would appreciate if you could help me finding a solution for this issue.

Comment: Check for non-printable characters and question marks.

Comment: I can't understand the need to count the lines, and its also hard to see where the illegal characters are without an example file path (same format different words)

Comment: Where do you call CountLinesInFile? What are you passing as string f?

Comment: I'm trying to count lines in the Program.cs (main file) and count the regex matches from the class (cisco.cs)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is most likely caused by the file name you are trying to open the StreamReader with, which I presume is invalid. Would you please post the filename you are trying to read, if checking it doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Andrej, 
I changed the file name and it works but I'm still not able to pass the class that actually does the regex on the passed file. 
I dont know what could be causing a incorrect path because the same code works if not in a separated class.c file.

Comment: What does the Lines(configfile) function do? What's the error you get now that you fixed the filename?